# PowerQuery - How can i make my queries more compact or a better way to do show the same results?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Im wondering how i could make my queries be less queries.
I have not created the queries inside Advanced Editor, but Ive started to look at this and try to use it more.

I have a database called Source_VSLösenord, which has all tickets from a department, and another database called Source_Members which has both inactive and active members.
Im filtering out for each category (Melior, PMO, Obstetrix, Orbit), and then filtering for each type (Created, Resolved, Handled) done by each member, and adding a column that defines which type it is for example: Created_Melior, Resolved_Melior.

Excluding Source, i use 9 queries to then append these to 1. So my question is, can you give/educate me 1 or a few better ways to do this?

I want to learn more, Im just a "intermediate" beginner here, so i have a follow up question as well which is how can i convert the column "Month" to display monthname instead of numbers inside the Advanced Editor?

One more thing, i have a tricky task which havent had luck to find about in the webb. In query Handled_PMO im splitting specific strings with timestamp, i need to count as 1 row if the same individual entered a log within 10 minutes in "this" ticket.

I couldnt find upload-button so here below is the code:

```
---------Source: VSLösenord---------------------------
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\kadirdil\OneDrive - Tietoevry\The Ledger\The Book Of VS\Lösenordshantering\Source\00_Lösenord_280422.xlsx"), null, true),

    Source_VSLösenord_Table = Source{[Item="Source_VSLösenord",Kind="Table"]}[Data],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source_VSLösenord_Table,{{"Category", type text}, {"Subcategory", type text}, {"Number", type text}, {"Created", type datetime}, {"Resolved", type datetime}, {"Service", type text}, {"Configuration item", type text}, {"Short description", type text}, {"Description", type text}, {"Affected User", type text}, {"Reported by", type text}, {"Assigned to", type text}, {"Created by group", type text}, {"Created by", Int64.Type}, {"Opened by", type text}, {"Assignment group", type text}, {"Closed by", type text}, {"Resolved by", type text}, {"Resolution code", type text}, {"Resolution notes", type text}, {"Additional comments", type text}, {"Comments and Work notes", type text}, {"Work notes", type text}, {"On Hold Count", Int64.Type}, {"On hold reason", type any}, {"Reassignment count", Int64.Type}, {"Reopen count", Int64.Type}}),

    #"Create Fixed Service" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Fixed Service", each if Text.Contains([Service], "Melior") then "Melior" else if Text.Contains([Service], "Orbit") then "Orbit" else if Text.Contains([Service], "PMO") then "PMO" else if Text.Contains([Service], "Obstetrix") then "Obstetrix" else "Null"),

    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Create Fixed Service",{"Fixed Service", "Number", "Category", "Subcategory", "Created", "Resolved", "Service", "Configuration item", "Short description", "Description", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Assigned to", "Created by group", "Created by", "Opened by", "Assignment group", "Closed by", "Resolved by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),

    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each ([Category] = "Fråga / Stöd") and ([Subcategory] = "Lösenord")),

    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Reopen count", Order.Descending}}),
    
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows", {"Number"})
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
    

---------Source: Members---------------------------
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Source_Members"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Displayname", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Active", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
    

---------Query: Created_Melior---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered Melior" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "Melior")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Melior",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Resolved", "Service", "Configuration item", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Closed by", "Resolved by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each "Melior, Created"),
    Essential = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Short description", "Description", "Assigned to", "Created by group", "Created by", "Assignment group", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Essential,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Created", "Opened by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Created", "Date"}, {"Opened by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
    
    
---------Query: Created_PMO---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered PMO" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "PMO")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered PMO",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Resolved", "Service", "Configuration item", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Closed by", "Resolved by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each "PMO, Created"),
    Essential = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Short description", "Description", "Assigned to", "Created by group", "Created by", "Assignment group", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Essential,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Created", "Opened by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Created", "Date"}, {"Opened by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
    
    
---------Query: Created_Obstetrix---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered Obstetrix" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "Obstetrix")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Obstetrix",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Resolved", "Service", "Configuration item", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Closed by", "Resolved by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each "Obstetrix, Created"),
    Essential = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Short description", "Description", "Assigned to", "Created by group", "Created by", "Assignment group", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Essential,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Created", "Opened by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Created", "Date"}, {"Opened by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
    
    
---------Query: Created_Orbit---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered Orbit" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "Orbit")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Orbit",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Resolved", "Service", "Configuration item", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Closed by", "Resolved by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each "Orbit, Created"),
    Essential = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Short description", "Description", "Assigned to", "Created by group", "Created by", "Assignment group", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Essential,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Created", "Opened by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Created", "Date"}, {"Opened by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
    

---------Query: Resolved_Melior---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered Melior" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "Melior")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Melior",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Created", "Service", "Configuration item", "Short description", "Description", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Created by group", "Created by", "Opened by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each "Melior, Resolved"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Assigned to", "Assignment group", "Closed by", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Resolved", "Resolved by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Resolved", "Date"}, {"Resolved by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
    
    
---------Query: Resolved_PMO---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered PMO" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "PMO")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered PMO",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Created", "Service", "Configuration item", "Short description", "Description", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Created by group", "Created by", "Opened by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each "PMO, Resolved"),
    Custom1 = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Assigned to", "Assignment group", "Closed by", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Custom1,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Resolved", "Resolved by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Resolved", "Date"}, {"Resolved by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
    
    
---------Query: Resolved_Obstetrix---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered Obstetrix" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "Obstetrix")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Obstetrix",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Created", "Service", "Configuration item", "Short description", "Description", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Created by group", "Created by", "Opened by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each "Obstetrix, Resolved"),
    Custom1 = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Assigned to", "Assignment group", "Closed by", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Custom1,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Resolved", "Resolved by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Resolved", "Date"}, {"Resolved by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
    
    
---------Query: Resolved_Orbit---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered Orbit" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "Orbit")),
    Orbit = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Orbit",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Created", "Service", "Configuration item", "Short description", "Description", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Created by group", "Created by", "Opened by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Add Column, Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(Orbit, "Count Type", each "Orbit, Resolved"),
    Custom1 = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Column, Count Type",{"Assigned to", "Assignment group", "Closed by", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Custom1,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Resolved", "Resolved by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Resolved", "Date"}, {"Resolved by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"


---------Query: Handled_PMO---------------------------
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered PMO" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Fixed Service] = "PMO")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered PMO",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Created", "Resolved", "Service", "Configuration item", "Short description", "Description", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Assigned to", "Created by group", "Created by", "Opened by", "Assignment group", "Closed by", "Resolved by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Select List" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "List", each List.Select(Text.Split([Comments and Work notes], "#(lf)"), each not Text.Contains(_, "System") and (Text.EndsWith(_, "(Work notes)") or Text.EndsWith(_, "(Additional comments)")))),
    Distinct = Table.AddColumn(#"Select List", "List.1", each Table.Distinct(Table.FromList(List.Transform ( [List], each Text.Start(_, 19) & ","  & Text.Range(_, 22, Text.PositionOf(_, "(")-22)), null, {"Date", "UserName"}))),
    #"Table Set" = Table.AddColumn(#"Distinct", "List.2", each [List.1]),
    #"Table show Date" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Table Set", "List.1", {"Date"}, {"List.Date"}),
    #"Table show Agent" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Table show Date", "List.2", {"UserName"}, {"List.Agent"}),
    Cleaned = Table.TransformColumns(#"Table show Agent",{{"List.Agent", Text.Clean, type text}}),
    Trimmed = Table.TransformColumns(#"Cleaned",{{"List.Agent", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(Trimmed, "Count Type", each "PMO, Handled"),
    Essential = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes", "Work notes", "List"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Essential,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "List.Date", "List.Agent"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"List.Date", "Date"}, {"List.Agent", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"


---------Query: Appended---------------------------
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Grouped_Created_Melior, Grouped_Created_PMO, Grouped_Created_Obstetrix, Grouped_Created_Orbit, Grouped_Handled_PMO, Grouped_Resolved_Melior, Grouped_Resolved_PMO, Grouped_Resolved_Obstetrix, Grouped_Resolved_Orbit}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-GB"), "Date", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Date.1", "Date.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Date.1", type date}, {"Date.2", type time}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type1", {{"Date.1", type text}}, "en-GB"), "Date.1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Date.1.1", "Date.1.2", "Date.1.3"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Date.1.1", Int64.Type}, {"Date.1.2", Int64.Type}, {"Date.1.3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"Date.1.1", "Day"}, {"Date.1.2", "Month"}, {"Date.1.3", "Year"}, {"Date.2", "TimeStamp"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Year", "Month", "Day", "TimeStamp", "Agent"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Reordered Columns", {"Agent"}, Source_Members, {"Name"}, "Source_Members", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Source_Members" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Source_Members", {"Name"}, {"Source_Members.Name"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Source_Members", each ([Source_Members.Name] <> null))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something. The only difference between almost all of them (except PMO) seems to be the name of [Fixed Service]. Then you filter on [Fixed Service] and add a column that says "(service) Resolved", then put all those together? Is there anything else going on?

Comment: @horseyride 
Each ticket or every row in Source_VSLösenord have a column with the agents name who created the ticket, and another column with the agents name who resolved the ticket, as well as columns for date/time respectively.

Im splitting the tickets to 2 list, one row for created the ticket and 1 row for resolving the ticket. The difference with Handled_PMO is that someone or member creates the ticket, then member send email and paus the ticket, and then member resolves the ticket. So there is an extra step in the process compared to the others fixed services.

Comment: Sorry ,that does not answer my question. Looks to me that all the created and resolved queries except Handled_PMO are doing the exact same thing and I don't understand why its necessary to filter them separately

Comment: @horseyride

Im filtering separately cuz im not sure how to do it with one section of code, hence my threadquestion - How to do combine/merge it?
Sry for afk, vacation just started and been with my kid, shared custody.

Answer (score 0):

how about replacing all the created and resolved ones with just two instead of eight

```
---------Query: Created
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Fixed Service] = "Melior" or [Fixed Service] = "PMO" or [Fixed Service] = "Obstetrix" or [Fixed Service] = "Orbit"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Resolved", "Service", "Configuration item", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Closed by", "Resolved by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each [Fixed Service] & ", Created"),
    Essential = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Short description", "Description", "Assigned to", "Created by group", "Created by", "Assignment group", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Essential,{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Created", "Opened by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Created", "Date"}, {"Opened by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
    
---------Query: Resolved
let
    Source = #"Source_VSLösenord",
    #"Filtered" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Fixed Service] = "Melior" or [Fixed Service] = "PMO" or [Fixed Service] = "Obstetrix" or [Fixed Service] = "Orbit"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered",{"Category", "Subcategory", "Created", "Service", "Configuration item", "Short description", "Description", "Affected User", "Reported by", "Created by group", "Created by", "Opened by", "Resolution code", "Resolution notes", "Work notes", "On Hold Count", "On hold reason", "Reassignment count", "Reopen count"}),
    #"Added Count Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count Type", each [Fixed Service] & ", Resolved"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Count Type",{"Assigned to", "Assignment group", "Closed by", "Additional comments", "Comments and Work notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Fixed Service", "Count Type", "Number", "Resolved", "Resolved by"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Resolved", "Date"}, {"Resolved by", "Agent"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: Ahh wonderful thank you, didn't know it could be filtered like that.